# Need working example of EventFiringWebDriver and OnFindingElement or OnElementClicked usage in Selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, onclicklistener

I am a novice to both Selenium and C#. Can someone please help me with an working example of how to write a message to a log file or Console.WriteLine upon clicking an element or finding an element using EventFiringWebDriver? I am looking for C# and not Java.

Comment: He has asked a valid question about EventFiringWebDriver in Selenium in C#. I have posted an answer below.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using Statements:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Events;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Extensions;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
```

Initialize the WebDriver:

```
IWebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
var firingDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(WebDriver);

firingDriver.ExceptionThrown +=
    new EventHandler<WebDriverExceptionEventArgs>(firingDriver_ExceptionThrown);

firingDriver.ElementClicked +=
    new EventHandler<WebElementEventArgs>(firingDriver_ElementClicked);

firingDriver.FindElementCompleted +=
    new EventHandler<FindElementEventArgs>(firingDriver_FindElementCompleted);

webDriver = firingDriver; // this is important!
```

Logging Methods:

```
static void firingDriver_ExceptionThrown(object sender, WebDriverExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ThrownException.Message);
}

static void firingDriver_ElementClicked(object sender, WebElementEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Element);
}

static void firingDriver_FindElementCompleted(object sender, FindElementEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.FindMethod);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why my answer is down voted? I have provided a working example of eventFiringWebDriver in c#

Comment: To be clear, this captures events that are sent through the driver, it's not for capturing user events.